# Basic python-creating user defined function

Tags: python-3.x

I have a very basic doubt. I am currently using python3.0

Below is the code I have created for user-defined function called `double()`

Code:

```
def double(i):
    for n in range(2,5):
        x=i**n
        print(x)
    return(x)
print(double(2))
```

> output: 4 8 16 16

I got 16 displayed twice, what is the error?

Comment: just write `double(2)` intead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the solution, Hope this will help you

```
def double(i):
    for n in range(2,5):
        x=i**n
        print(x)
    return(x)

double(2) # don't write print here because you already print inside function
```

Answer (score 0):

See the below code:

```
def double(i):
   for n in range(2,5):
      x=i**n
      print(x)
double(2)
```

Just call the function as you are printing the values inside the double function.
Also since all the required values are printed inside the function you need not return anything from the function.